# How to find index jump and it's time value in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I read a [csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16NrzcmdoYUmzI6aq2DjcAW98NqPuzIIL/view?usp=sharing), create a df and access it's selected df that fits a condition in order to calculate a time difference. I get selected df's time difference by subtracting last value from the first value of `$Time` column.

What I want to do is to calculate and print two time differences, where selected df's index has a jump. In other words, I would like to print first time difference between indexes 250-262 and the second one between 268 and 271.

Selected df for the condition: all values in column 'TR_A_00' which are less than 95% of its intial value.

```
         $Time      TR_A_00    TR_A_01  TR_A_02
250  17:57:15.000  621.00000    631.2  633.20000
251  17:57:15.040  608.00000    625.0  629.80000
252  17:57:15.080  605.80000    620.0  629.40000
253  17:57:15.120  605.20000    620.0  630.60004
254  17:57:15.160  605.60004    620.0  631.00000
255  17:57:15.200  605.40000    620.0  632.00000
256  17:57:15.240  606.80000    621.8  634.60004
257  17:57:15.280  608.60004    622.8  635.60004
258  17:57:15.320  609.80000    624.4  637.60004
259  17:57:15.360  614.20000    628.0  641.20000
260  17:57:15.400  616.20000    629.0  642.60004
261  17:57:15.440  617.20000    630.8  644.40000
262  17:57:15.480  621.00000    634.2  648.20000     -> Here is the index jump
268  17:57:15.720  608.40000    599.0  613.80000
269  17:57:15.760  589.60004    589.8  599.80000
270  17:57:15.800  594.40000    595.2  601.60004
271  17:57:15.840  619.00000    626.2  631.20000
```

my code gives me the selected df and time difference between first and last row:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

data = pd.read_csv('24WEA84562_2021-05-23_17-57-15_ST193.csv', usecols=['$Time', 'TR_A_00', 'TR_A_01', 'TR_A_02'])

v12 = data['TR_A_00']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['$Time', 'TR_A_00', 'TR_A_01', 'TR_A_02'])
beginning_V12 = v12[0]
fault_assumption = 0.95
threshold_V12 = beginning_V12 * fault_assumption
selected_rows_V12 = df[df.TR_A_00 < threshold_V12]

first_row_time_V12 = selected_rows_V12['$Time'].iloc[0]
last_row_time_V12 = selected_rows_V12['$Time'].iloc[-1]

first_row_time_V12 = datetime.strptime(first_row_time_V12, '%H:%M:%S.%f')
last_row_time_V12 = datetime.strptime(last_row_time_V12, '%H:%M:%S.%f')

difference_time_V12 = last_row_time_V12 - first_row_time_V12
diff_in_ms_V12 = difference_time_V12.total_seconds() * 1000

print(selected_rows_V12)
```

**Edit for mozway's answer**

two slots I need to print:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your data, zoomed on the interesting part (index: 230–300):
[image: data]

To locate the sharp changes, you can calculate a gradient (~derivative). For this you apply Δy/Δx, in your case the x intervals are constant so you could just do with Δy.

```
# make sure "$Time" is of datetime type:
data['$Time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['$Time'])
# calculate the gradient
gradient = data['TR_A_02'].diff().div(data['$Time'].diff().dt.total_seconds())

# calculate the values below threshold and the first jump:
isbelow = gradient.lt(-50)
first_jump = isbelow.ne(isbelow.shift().fillna(False))&isbelow
before_jump = first_jump.shift(-1).fillna(False)

# plot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
zoom = pd.IndexSlice[230:300]
gradient.loc[zoom].plot(label='gradient')
gradient[gradient.lt(-50)].plot(marker='s', ls='', label='values below thresh')
gradient.loc[first_jump[first_jump].index].plot(marker='P', ls='', label='jump')
gradient.loc[before_jump[before_jump].index].plot(marker='P', ls='', label='before jump')
plt.legend()
```

output:

[image: gradient and points]

On original data:

```
data.loc[zoom, 'TR_A_02'].plot(label='gradient')
data.loc[first_jump[first_jump].index, 'TR_A_02'].plot(marker='P', ls='', label='jump')
data.loc[before_jump[before_jump].index, 'TR_A_02'].plot(marker='P', ls='', label='before jump')
plt.legend()
```

[image: jump on original data]

#### how to compute the time difference as defined in question

```
# set the threshold at 640
islower = data['TR_A_02'].lt(640)
# determine the start and stop position for each peak
points = (islower&~islower.shift(fill_value=False)).cumsum().mul(islower)
points = points[points.gt(0)]
# compute the difference from the "$Time" column
points.groupby(points).apply(lambda s: data.loc[s.index[-1], '$Time']-data.loc[s.index[0], '$Time']).dt.total_seconds()
```

output (in seconds):

```
TR_A_02
1    0.32
2    0.12
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for the graphical explanation. I think I need one step more. I've edited my question and printed your graph for 'TR_A_00' which goes twice up and down the threshold. In this way I have two time slots which I have to calculate and print in millisecond . Could you please clarify, how I can print these two time differences between the points 1-2 and 3-4 in the image I've added. 

point 1 corresponds to index 250, point 2 to 262 and this is the first time slot I need to print. Time slot between Point 3 and 4 correspond to time difference between indexes 268 and 270

Comment: I updated the answer to compute the time difference

Comment: In this way I've noticed that I have to check `shift()` and `cumsum()` methods again. I really appreciate your time,  thank you! @mozway